# Django Registration Redux: Add Fields To User Profile error

Tags: django, registration, redux

I am trying to add some extended fields to the user, but it only save the user info but not the extra field in the new table.

This is the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
```

Here the form:

```
class UserProfileRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    field = forms.CharField()
```

regbackend.py

```
class UserRegistrationView(RegistrationView):

    form_class = UserProfileRegistrationForm

    def register(self, request, form_class):
        new_user = super(UserRegistrationView, self).register(request, form_class)
        new_user.field = form_class.cleaned_data['field']
        new_user.save()
        user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
        user_profile.field = form_class.cleaned_data['field']
        user_profile.save()
        return user_profile
```

And the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', index_view),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', regbackend.UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: When i register a new user, it give me this error: gaierror at /accounts/register/
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: gaierror
Exception Value: 
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 557
Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.10

Comment: Can you show the email setup in your setting file please? or how do you setup?

Comment: I do apology I miss understand the error, my question was related to other error not yours.